# Why Does my cat not meow?

Tags: cats, behavior

My cat is about a year old, we got him from a farm. And there they said his mother abandoned him there but he was taken in by another cat with kitten a couple weeks older than him. And they also said he did't drink much or eat much either. So when we took him in we tried to make sure he drank more water and eat more which he slowly did. But whoever he would try to meow and he this still happens whoever he tries to meow and it barley comes out like it's kinda raspy and not very loud at all. And at this point he just never meows but he does tend to purr a lot but he never meows and rarely ever hisses when play/fighting with our other cat who is about the same age but not related and she is VERY vocal and constantly meowing. IDK what is wrong with him he's been neutered and has had his shots and never has had surgery and any accidents that I know of. Someone help bc I'm a lil worried about him and want to know why he doesn't meow.  also not sure what bread he is but I'm pretty sure he's an American Black Shorthair.(haven't gone to a vet yet about this).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation with my cats. My 15 year old growls when the two year old cat tries to play with her roughly, hisses when she's jumped on, meows when hungry, purrs when happy, and also has a happy sort of meow to greet. The only sound I've heard my two year old stray make is a rumbling sound. She never meows, never growls, never hisses, and will purr on occasion but honestly with the other cat being so loud and purring almost constantly unless she's batting around the two year old, I might just be comparing the 2 year old's purr to an unfair opponent.

Even that rumble that the younger cat makes is hard to hear. When she opens her mouth to meow a strange rapsy sound, that probably was supposed to be a greeting meow but instead turned into a muted sound, comes out. I figured it was because she was never taught to meow so there her vocal cords haven't been used enough to be louder. Since she was a stray and never really had a home, I figured that it was because she just didn't know how to really talk unlike my older cat who was a stray but was probably pre-owned and probably left behind so therefore given lots of opportunities to talk.

Interestingly enough my youngest cat is thought to be an American Shorthair. Perhaps its the breed?